# Jenkins: Changing Console Output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working in jenkins.
I'd like to put some specified text in the Console Output in a specified colour.

For example:

My output is:

---

Commit message....
Creating dir: /var/lib/1
Creating dir: /var/lib/2

Job done

Build Successful

---

I'd like to out "Job Done" in red.

How can I do this?

I've looked at some plugins (The parsed log, AnsiColor Plugin) but I think I cannot do this using it.

Comment: Can I do it in the console output? I don't want to use another console....

Comment: See my answer. For some strange reason it didn't let me submit it yesterday.  It is parsing the Jenkins console log output.

Answer (score 0):

The [Log Parser](http://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) plugin will do what you want.

It allows you to specify your own rules with a parsing rules file and regular expression like syntax.